# SQL UPDATE values based on values of other rows

Tags: mysql

Current table:

```
id_product     id_shop       id_lang       description
---------------------------------------------------------
1                1             est         black
2                1             eng         brown
3                1             rus         red
1                2             est
2                2             eng
3                2             rus
```

Expected output:

```
id_product     id_shop       id_lang       description
---------------------------------------------------------
1                1             est         black
2                1             eng         brown
3                1             rus         red
1                2             est         black
2                2             eng         brown
3                2             rus         red
```

I need to copy the missing 'description' from id_lang 1 to id_lang 2 for respective products and languages.

I have aquery but this times out and results error:

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` t1, `ps_product_lang` t2
SET t1.description = t2.description
WHERE t1.id_shop = 2
AND t2.id_shop = 1
```

I would greatly appreciate if you could correct me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` t1 join `ps_product_lang` t2 on 
t1.id_lang = t2.id_lang
SET t1.description = t2.description
WHERE t1.id_shop = 2
AND t2.id_shop = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! First it affected 0 rows but I managed to correct it (removed and t1.id_shop = t2.id_shop): 

    UPDATE `ps_product_lang` t1 join `ps_product_lang` t2 on 
    t1.id_product = t2.id_product and t1.id_lang = t2.id_lang
    SET t1.description = t2.description
    WHERE t1.id_shop = 2
    AND t2.id_shop = 1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `id_lang` column to merge description as follow

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` t1
INNER JOIN `ps_product_lang` t2
ON t1.`id_lang` = t2.`id_lang`
SET t1.`description` = t2.`description`
WHERE t1.`description` IS NULL
```

You might need to change `IS NULL` to `= ''` if column contain blank values